# when i tried running tf_pose im having trouble

Tags: tensorflow

im trying to use tf-pose using tensorflow version2.

```
!git clone https://github.com/gsethi2409/tf-pose-estimation.git > /dev/null
%cd tf-pose-estimation
!pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

this from where i have cloned. but when i run the below code. it is showing an error.

```
!python run.py --model=mobilenet_thin --resize=432x368 --image=./images/p1.jpg
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "run.py", line 39, in
>
> e = TfPoseEstimator(get_graph_path(args.model), target_size=(w, h))   File "/content/tf-pose-estimation/tf_pose/estimator.py", line
> 337, in **init**
> self.tensor_image = self.graph.get_tensor_by_name('TfPoseEstimator/image:0')   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py",
> line 3902, in get_tensor_by_name
> return self.as_graph_element(name, allow_tensor=True, allow_operation=False)   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py",
> line 3726, in as_graph_element
> return self._as_graph_element_locked(obj, allow_tensor, allow_operation)   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py",
> line 3768, in _as_graph_element_locked
> "graph." % (repr(name), repr(op_name))) KeyError: "The name 'TfPoseEstimator/image:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist. The
> operation, 'TfPoseEstimator/image', does not exist in the graph."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In tf_pose/estimatory.py under the line that imports tensorflow add the following line

tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
[link](http://%20https://github.com/gsethi2409/tf-pose-estimation/issues/12#issuecomment-842847372)

Answer (score 0):

```
#vi tf_pose/estimator.py
#下記、”この行を追加”の行を追加します。

import logging
import math
import slidingwindow as sw
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import time
from tf_pose import common
from tf_pose.common import CocoPart
from tf_pose.tensblur.smoother import Smoother
from tensorflow.python.compiler.tensorrt import trt_convert as trt

# Added
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution() # この行を追加
#((( 以降、省略 )))
#https://take6shin-tech-diary.com/openpose-tensorflow2/
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).